# How to resolve java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, android, connection

**i am running my android application in device its not connecting to device.Its giving following error**

```
[2016-10-24 19:41:00 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring 127.0.0.1:5558
[2016-10-24 19:41:17 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2016-10-24 19:41:38 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: It seems you  don't have INTERNET permission

Comment: what is running at the port 5558 of your device ?

Comment: yes. running at the port 5558 of your device

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the server IP address and port number correct then my answer will not be so helpful.

***Otherwise:*** - Especially if you are using different JVMs for the client android app and the java program(your server). This could happen probably because they are both referencing different localhosts.

Open command line and issue the command `ipconfig`  you will get details about your network configurations. Instead of ***localhost*** Use the **physical address of your computer**(IPv4 address displayed on your terminal), it looks something like below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try giving user permission to your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```